# php logical 'and' not logical. (what am I missing here)

Tags: php

Given the following

```
expire date-> 2014-10-14 notify date-> 2014-10-06 current date-> 2014-10-08 Fine 
expire date-> 2014-10-07 notify date-> 2014-10-06 current date-> 2014-10-08 Expired 
expire date-> 2014-10-11 notify date-> 2014-10-06 current date-> 2014-10-08 Fine 
expire date-> 2014-10-05 notify date-> 2014-10-06 current date-> 2014-10-08 Expired
```

and the code

```
FOR loop (each row)
    if ($expire date < $current_date) {
        echo "Expired <BR/>";
    } elseif (($expire date >= $notify_date) && ($expire date <= $current_date)) {
        echo "Warning <BR/>";
    } elseif ($expire date > $notify_date) {
        echo "Fine <BR/>";
    }
END FOR
```

Why is the result
Fine
Expired
Fine
Expired

Why is `expire date  ->  2014-10-07` not printing `Warning`?

Comment: `expire date < $current_date` isn't valid syntax. Typo?

Comment: Is kindof Psuedo. Just go with the logic here

Comment: The reason is it hits the first `if` and since `10-7` is less than (before) the current date (`10-8`), it prints expired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `$vid_date` IS LESS THAN `$current_date`.  It meets your first conditional and never gets to the second. You typically need to arrange chained conditionals like this from most specific to most general.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with your first logic

```
 if (vid date < $current_date) {
        echo "Expired <BR/>";
```

try moving it to the last

Comment: Yes, I think I need some sleep. Bad logic sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try reordering your checks from most specific to least:

```
FOR loop (each row)
    if ((expire date >= $notify_date) && (expire date <= $current_date)) {
        echo "Warning <BR/>";
    } elseif (expire date < $current_date) {
        echo "Expired <BR/>";
    } elseif (expire date > $notify_date) {
        echo "Fine <BR/>";
    }
END FOR
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to arrange your conditionals around. Putting your first condition at the end resolve the issue.